# SQL multi shortest path query (A* algorithm)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am applying multi shortest path query however the SQL query indicate an error!

```
SELECT 
  "n1-centroid-shp".gid, 
  "n1-centroid-shp".geom, 
  "n1-desti-shp".gid, 
  "n1-desti-shp".geom
FROM 
  public."n1-centroid-shp", 
  public."n1-desti-shp";
  SELECT * FROM shotest_path_astar('..., 
  public."n1-centroid-shp",
  public."n1-desti-shp",
false,
false
FROM all_to_all;
```

`ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"
 LINE 14: FROM all_to_all;`

Comment: You wouldn't be burdened with double-quoting every column name if you used ANSI/ISO compliant names (underscore instead of hyphen). Your indentation scheme is confusing, and the second statement is missing a closing quote and a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the name of the function, as you can see from the [docs](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/astar/doc/index.html#pgr-astar) is pgr_astar (although possibly you are using an older version of pgRouting/Postgis?)

The format of the function is:

```
pgr_costResult[] pgr_astar(sql text, source integer, target integer,
                   directed boolean, has_rcost boolean);
```

where the return, pgr_costResult, is an array of rows, nodes, edges and costs. So, also from the docs, a sample query looks like:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
    FROM pgr_astar(
            'SELECT id, source, target, cost, x1, y1, x2, y2 FROM edge_table',
            4, 1, false, false
    );
```

ie, you have to pass in, as a text parameter, a SQL query that allows the graph to be built. You would need to rejoin the result back on your input routing table, if you want your query to return the actual geometries, eg,

```
SELECT id, id2 AS edge, geom
    FROM pgr_astar(
            'SELECT id, source, target, cost, x1, y1, x2, y2 FROM edge_table',
            4, 1, false, false
    ) astar 
INNER JOIN edge_table edge 
 ON astar.id2 = edge.id;
```

Comment: the city that I am working on has no data base, so I draw the geo-referenced shape files (shp) and connected between QGIS and PostGIS and pg Admin III, now the hole system is well organized and connected, and I can measure the shortest path between an origin and a destination individually, however is so time consuming! that is why I am trying to do it as a query from pg admin III.